# MySQL datatypes for business applications?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, types

Good day, I am confused with the datatype for `MySQL`.

I am using `decimal` as apparently it is the safest bet for accuracy in a business application. However, I find that when fields are returned I have values of `999999999.99`, where my datatype is DECIMAL(10,2). So the actual value has overflowed outside the `(10, 2)` parameter.

Would it be correct that even though I have specified 10 places before the comma and 2 places after the comma. **MySQL still stores the complete number**?

Also would it be possible to **turn off the maximum amount of digits** displayed before and after the comma?

Comment: `DECIMAL(10,2)` is *not* 10 digits before the point and 2 after; it is 10 digits in total, of which 2 are after the point (therefore 8 before it).  As for whether it's possible to "turn off" the maximum amount of digits - no, it is not (if nothing else, you'd be limited by the amount of available storage space).

Comment: if you need more digits, why not altering the column definition?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be correct that even though I have specified 10 places before the comma and 2 places after the comma. MySQL still stores the complete number?

No, it wouldn't.

First, [you specified 10 digits altogether](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html); two are to the right of the decimal point, and eight are to the left.

> Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the salary column range from -999.99 to 999.99.

Second, MySQL will silently convert the least significant digits to scale if there are more than two. That will probably look like MySQL truncates, but the actual behavior is platform-dependent. It will raise an error if you supply too many of the most significant digits.

Finally, when you're working with databases, the number of digits *displayed* has little to do with what a data type *is* or with what range of values it stores.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the number of digits total but I would like to know, and I think you have said it in a complicated way: Say for example `DECIMAL(10, 2)` and the returned result is: `32.4889932`, will `mysql` make further calculations with `32.49` or `32.4889932`?